# How to fix this loop, foreach command adds all variables which it shouldn't

Tags: netlogo

I used to have the following code, that worked:

```
to build-pipeline-32
    ask storage 32
  [ifelse subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible > 0
    [set pipeline 1]
    [set pipeline 0]
  ]
  ask storage 32
  [ifelse pipeline > 0
    [set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible]
    [set subsidy-port subsidy-port]
  ]
  ask storage 32
  [if pipeline = 1
    [create-link-from port 25]
 ]
end

to build-pipeline-33
    ask storage 33
  [ifelse subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible > 0
    [set pipeline 1]
    [set pipeline 0]
  ]
  ask storage 33
  [ifelse pipeline > 0
    [set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible]
    [set subsidy-port subsidy-port]
  ]
  ask storage 33
  [if pipeline = 1
    [create-link-from port 25]
  ]
end
```

Now I tried this to shorten it, because this just took so many code lines:

```
to build-pipeline
  foreach sort-on [who] storages
  [ifelse subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible > 0
    [set pipeline 1]
    [set pipeline 0]
  ]
  foreach sort-on [who] storages
  [ifelse pipeline > 0
    [set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible]
    [set subsidy-port subsidy-port]
  ]
  foreach sort-on [who] storages
  [if pipeline = 1
    [create-link-from port 25]
  ]
end
```

For some reason, it completely messes up the values of the subsidies. The upper part (setting pipeline value) and below part (creating link) do work. How can I fix this?

One other question: for some reason stack overflow makes me use the question help wizard which is super annoying because I cannot just select a piece of coppied code and format it as code in the question (with the {} option). For this question I had to indent 4 spaces manually for each line... Took forever. Cmd+K doesn't work either. Can I disable this question wizard? Thanks!!

Max

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the logic should be?

Comment: What basically happens is the following. Each tick the port gets a predefined amount of subsidy. Each storage location (12 in total) has predefined costs to build a pipeline to. There is a merit order of the storage locations, and the port decides to build as soon as there is enough capital. What happens here `[ifelse subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible > 0` is that the port checks if it can build based on revenue. This changes the value 'pipeline' of the storage from 0 to 1. The second line deducts the costs if it is a 1. The third part just creates a visual link if the line is built.

Comment: Simply want to loop it, otherwise the code becomes messy and long. Very new to netlogo and programming so still struggling with the commands and possibilities.

Comment: Hi @mattsap . Hope I am not bothering you. Currently still struggling with the above. For some reason the model deducts 12x the costs of the pipeline from the cashflow when it is built. I just don't see why it does that. I wish you to give you some more code, but it is getting quite long, so I can't copy it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your model deducts 12x the pipeline costs is because it builds 12 pipeline extensions as soon as there is capital available. You don't deduct the cost until the second `foreach` but you assign whether or not an extension will be built in the first `foreach`.

I think you want this (it puts the cost change into the same [ ] so will occur before testing the next possible extension):

```
to build-pipeline
  foreach sort-on [who] storages
  [ ifelse subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible > 0
    [ set pipeline 1
      set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible
      create-link-from port 25
    [ set pipeline 0
      set subsidy-port subsidy-port  ; has no effect, can be deleted
    ]
  ]
end
```

Also, if the only purpose of the pipeline variable is to be 1 or 0 to indicate whether an extension is to be built, this is even easier:

```
to build-pipeline
  foreach sort-on [who] storages
  [ if subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible > 0
    [ set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible
      create-link-from port 25
  ]
end
```

In your comments, you indicated that there is a merit order of pipeline extensions. It is almost always bad coding to use `who` in NetLogo. The variable `who` is simply the order the storages are created, tying that to merit removes all flexibility. What happens if later you want a different calculation of merit? The `who` cannot be changed. What you probably want is to assign a variable named merit for each storage and sort on that variable instead.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your help. I think this is the way to go. However, if I use the above code, the line: `set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible` causes it stop looping for some reason. If I remove this part, it all works and all the links are made with the different storages. Is there a method to address the costs of that specific pipeline location? Each location has different costs.

Comment: So, something like `set subsidy-port subsidy-port - pipeline-cost-extensible (of that location)`, because now it deducts a different amount I believe

Comment: Also, the variable pipeline stays 0 where it should be set to 1.

Comment: I can't answer any of your comments without seeing how you've set up the model. For example, I had thought that pipeline-cost-extensible was a global variable, but it now appears to be a variable of a location. Is a location the same as a storage? If so, this code will work anyway. As to pipeline being 0/1, the second version should only be used if the pipeline 0/1 is meaningless outside this block of code, as stated in the answer.

Comment: Ask a separate question about the stop looping problem, since there's nothing here that is likely to cause it (that I can see). And don't just say 'stops looping'. How do you know it stops looping? Does it give an error message? Or are you claiming it only runs through once? What values of subsidy-port and pipeline--cost-extensible going into the loop? To get a useful answer, you need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the help. We managed to create some work around for now, problem was in different parts of the code. It's getting quite long now so that makes it hard to get specific sometimes when the error is somewhere else. Thanks again for all the help!!